# Creating density plots with two variables (2D) and overlaying the plots for two dataframes in the same plot for comparison

Tags: r, plot

I have two dataframes of similar type. I want to create density plots using two columns (bi-variate) from each dataframe in R. And then overlay these two density plots onto the same graph for comparison. Also, I want to know if I can find the mean, median and standard deviation after plotting these density plots and compare them. For example, I have two dataframes like below (much bigger). I want to plot Avg in the X and Dmel_pl in the Y axis and create a density plot for the first dataframe df1. And then repeat the same thing for the second dataframe df2 by placing Avy in X and Dpse_pl in Y axis. To compare both the density plots I want to create them in the same graph and overlay them. Also from these two density plots, I want to calculate the mean, median, std dev and other common statistical measures to compare the density plots and make a correlation between them. This is the code for data frame 1:

```
df1 <- data.frame (Avg = c(19,15,25,16,1.5,23,10),
                  Dmel_pl= c(42,58,87.45,93.24,70.34,55.90,56.12))
```

And this is the code for the second data frame:

```
df2 <- data.frame (Avg = c(10,13,22,34,8,25),
                  Dpse_pl= c(67,95.05,49.43,70.34,43.80,57.32))
```

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput` and code you tried?

Comment: Please do not give your data in an image.  No one wants to type it in again. instead, use `dput` to get a text version of your data and paste it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option to achieve this

First you can merge all your data frames into a single one:

```
library(tidyverse)
df3 = df1 %>% full_join(df2, by = "Avg") %>% 
  pivot_longer(!Avg, names_to = "Pl", values_to = "values") %>% 
  filter(!is.na(values))
```

And then create your plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df3, aes(x=Avg, y=values, colour = Pl))+
  geom_density2d()+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~Pl)+
  theme_bw()
```

*You can overlay the 2 groups by removing the `facet_wrap` line in the call for the plot*
[image]

Finally one of the option for classic stats is the `describeBy` function from the `psych` package

```
library(psych)
describeBy(df3$values, group=df3$Pl)

 Descriptive statistics by group 
group: Dmel_pl
   vars n  mean    sd median trimmed  mad min   max range skew kurtosis se
X1    1 7 66.15 18.53     58   66.15 18.3  42 93.24 51.24 0.29    -1.65  7
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
group: Dpse_pl
   vars n  mean    sd median trimmed  mad  min   max range skew kurtosis   se
X1    1 6 63.82 18.32  62.16   63.82 15.5 43.8 95.05 51.25 0.53    -1.29 7.48
```